# Android indoor directions with Google api

Tags: android, maps, directions

I currently have an app which displays a map fragment and can display navigation to a given point. The indoor maps is enabled and the building I'm trying to use does have indoor maps, but it only navigates to outside the building even when the transport mode is set to walking.

Is there currently any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there are many devices with such advanced GPS accuracy, to implement make use of indoor directions.

Comment: Once the direction API (or otherwise) can calculate the route and not track the user taking it, that's all i'd need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) does not support this feature for now.
Even if you select the correct [travel mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), which should be walking, the route is traced on the nearest road and not on the indoor path.

I'm also waiting for this option to be released, since it is currently possible to get this outcome using Google's own Maps web app.

Comment: Ya I ended up using normal google maps with floor plan overlays. I found even using Googles own app that it was still pretty buggy but hopefully they will update the directions API soon, there's a lot of potential for it.

Answer (score 1):

My graduate project is about indoor positioning when GPS is not available in android. The answer is yes, but there is not easy way. Hard way to do this but accuracy not good as good the GPS. There are two main approach to get location.

***Approaches***

**1. Sensor-Fusion:** This method for the get **relative** location. Using built-in sensors (gyroscope, accelerometer, compass) calculate the **distance & direction** over time. So you get the new location adding this value to old location. It also called **dead-reckoning**.

**2. Wi-fi Signal Strength:** If there are two or more a.p. which locations are known before, use the signal strengths to estimate your location. This idea a bit similar to how GPS works.

***Weak Sides***

**1. Sensor-Fusion:** Calculating new location error(e0) occur. When calculating next new location new error(e1) occurs again. So you get new location with e0+e1. I mean error groves exponentially over time.

**2. Wi-fi Signal Strength:** Some items can block the a.p. So you get weak signal strength and calculate wrong location.

**Finally**
I use first approach for short time(10sec). Second approach to correct location(every 10sec). So you get the best results for long & short time.

Source

- Deeper explaination at this [pdf](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/www/files/publications/public/abr28/ojw28_thesis.pdf).
- open source android app using first [approach](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adaptivedr/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although the main objective for me is to mark the path from point A to point B inside a building that has indoor maps. Whether or not their GPS can track them following the route will be a bonus.

Comment: If the start point of your location is known, you can use sensor-fusion method. There is a link above for open source app using this method.