# How to draw polyline from current location to co-ordinates using Google Maps SDK and Directions API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

I am using the Google's Android Maps API for indoor mapping in our app. It displays the indoor map correctly (by default but I am also setting `mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);`). I am calling the Directions API to get the co-ordinates between my current location and predefined co-ordinates to plot the polyline on the indoor map. However, the Directions API always returns outside walking co-ordinates to the building entrance.

What I need to do is display custom selectable markers on the map that will plot the poly from location to that point, just as the Google Maps app does. I also need these markers to respect which floor they are on, i.e. when a different floor is selected, the markers will not show. I think I can do this with `setOnIndoorStateChangeListener`.

I am passing an API key with the query, which works from the browser.

Is there something I am missing in the docs for this indoor maps/directions/ polyline plotting?

Comment: Can you add your request code? Have you set the` travelMode` to walking or transit? Check this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes) for travelMode implementation. If error still persists I think, it is not yet possible in Google [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/releases). Also check this [previous ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677292/android-indoor-directions-with-google-api)

Comment: Request:   
```https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=<CO-ORDS>&destination=<CO-ORDS>&sensor=false&mode=walking&key=<API-KEY>```